# HttpClient to call Azure AD-protected site

Tags: c#, azure, cookies, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

Following some Microsoft samples, I got to this point:

**ASP.NET Core setup:**

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
{
    ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAD:ClientId"],
    Authority = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:Authority"],
    ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
});
```

**AuthorizationTest endpoint:**

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    return Ok("SAMPLE TEXT - if you can read this then call it a day :)");
}
```

**Client:**

```
try
{
   var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(WebApiResourceId, WebApiClientId, WebApiRedirectUri, new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto));
   authorizedClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);

   var authorizedMessage = await authorizedClient.GetAsync("/AuthorizationTest");
   var statusCode = authorizedMessage.StatusCode.ToString();
   var message = await authorizedMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   webBrowser.NavigateToString(message);
 }
```

And the `authorizedClient` is initiated as:

```
private static HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    AllowAutoRedirect = true,
    CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(),
    UseCookies = true
 };
 private static HttpClient authorizedClient = new HttpClient(handler, false) { BaseAddress = WebApiBaseUri };
```

I used to initialize it only with the BaseAddress, and later added the handler following an answer here on So.

**The problem:**
Even though I get the token from AAD correctly, the response from the `WEB API` endpoint is an HTML (after an auto-redirect) that is the MS login page with the error "`Your browser is set to block cookies.....`"

What should I change to make the HttpClient work? Or can I change the WebApi configuration to not use cookies? For the latter option I couldn't find any other alternative.

Comment: You should be using Azure AD Bearer token authentication, not Open ID Connect. What you get from Azure AD is a token used for APIs, while the Open ID Connect middleware is for user-facing applications (which redirects the user to AAD for sign-in if it receives a challenge).

Comment: @juunas any examples/packages I should be looking at?

Comment: The package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` is typically used, you can find an example API [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore/blob/master/TodoListService/project.json).

Comment: @juunas how would that validate the token in Azure? I know the library

Comment: What it does is when it gets a JSON Web Token, it checks to see it is valid, and authenticates the user. Your client should get the access token as you are doing now, and attach it to every request.

Comment: @juunas Thanks so much, that did it. If you post an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you need to use the JWT bearer token middleware from the package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer`.

The Open ID Connect middleware is designed to redirect a user to a sign in page, not for authenticating access tokens. An example usage of the JWT bearer token middleware can be found here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore/blob/master/TodoListService/Startup.cs.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this thread: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues/514 - it is showing the scenario you are trying to achieve.